# How to use SerialPort SerialDataReceived help

Tags: c#, serial-port

Not sure how to handle SerialPort DataReceived.
Scenario

I have an application that communicate with a device and this device returns a status .This happens in different stages EG

public enum ActionState
{
  Started,
  InProgress,
  Completed
etc...
}

Now if I were to use the DataReceivedEventHandler how can I tell what Method is executing? eg Action1 or Action2 etc...?
I also want to include some sort of timeout when getting back stuff from device.
Any example or advice?

```
    public ActionState Action1
    {
        serialPort.write(myData);
        string result=serialPort.ReadExisting());


        //convertTo ActionState and return
         return ConvertToActionState(result);
    }

    public ActionState Action2
    {
        serialPort.write(myData);
        string result=serialPort.ReadExisting());

        //convertTo ActionState and return
         return ConvertToActionState(result);
    }


    private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
      //How can I use this to detect which method is firing and set the actionState Enum accordingly?
    }

    private ActionState(string result)
    {
       if(result==1)
          return ActionState.Started;
       else if (result==2)
          return ActionState.Completed

      etc...

    }
```

Comment: What is this ? C# ? Java ? Some tags would help...

Comment: Its C#, the DataReceived() method is common to the serial port class

Answer (score 1):

The event DataReceived is trigger by the serialport when have some data to read, even Eof character is received. Tipicaly this event is used to get that data and start a process with it or store. For example, the serialport read a barcode and find it on the database.

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                    object sender,
                    SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    if(!String.IsEmptyOrNull( indata)) 
    {
        AddProductToCart(indata);
    }
}
```